# Recurrence Relations: Proving (n/2) + (n/2) = O(n)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

So say I have an algorithm like this:

```
void dummy_algorithm(int a[]) {
   int center = floor(a.length/2);
   //For reference purposes: Loop 1  
   for(int i = 0; i < center; i++) {
       //The best code you've ever seen
   }
   //Loop 2
   for(int j = center + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      //Slightly less awesome code
   }
}
```

It's pretty basic stuff. I know both loops iterate through one half of the array, thus giving each an (n/2) complexity. However, the total work the method does is obviously O(n).

So, my question is: How do I prove (via a recurrence relation) that this algorithm is O(n)? Or am I wrong on this altogether?

Note: I cannot combine the two loops into one. They preform actions that eventually go into recursive calls. Anything else you can think of isn't allowed. There are a lot of constraints on this problem.

Comment: Do you really need to prove that O(n/2 + n/2) is in O(n)? It's what I'd call trivial.

Comment: Your code uses two loops, so assuming the content of the loops are both `O(n)`, then you actually have `O(n) + O(n)`, which is just `O(2n)` which is the same as `O(n)`.

Comment: A recurrence relation is for analyzing a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really looking for a proof that *O(x) + O(y) = O(x+y)*, it would work along these lines:

R1 ∈ O(x) ∧ R2 ∈ O(y)
⇒ ∃ a. R1 < ax ∧ ∃ b. R2 < by
⇒ ∃ a, b. R1 < ax ∧ R2 < by
⇒ ∃ a, b. R1+R2 < ax + by
⇒ ∃ a, b. c=max(a,b) ∧ R1+R2 < cx + cy
⇒ ∃ c. R1+R2 < c(x+y)
⇒ R1+R2 ∈ O(x+y)

Comment: This only shows O(x) + O(y) \subseteq O(x+y), but the other direction is shown analogously. Hence +1.

Comment: Thanks guys! Provided much need clarity!

Answer (score 0):

```
  (N/2) + (N/2)
= 2*(N/2)
= 2N/2
= N
```

Comment: @Kolink Well almost (maybe not when proving, but when looking for an answer).

Comment: @Kolink `O(N/2)` with all standard algebra rules is perfectly valid asymptotic math.  It just happens to be the same as `O(N)`.

Comment: O(N) + O(N) is not O(2N). It is still O(N).

Comment: @Sani: It is both, since O(2N) = O(N). Ignoring constant factors is the whole reason d'etre of big-O....

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity (and whether you need a recurrence relation) **depends on what you do in the loops**, i.e. what the complexity of

```
//The best code you've ever seen (*complexity1*)
```

and

```
 //Slightly less awesome code (*complexity2*)
```

is.

**If each iteration only requires a constant amount of time**, i.e. *complexity1* and *complexity2* in O(1), then the total complexity will be n*O(1) = O(n). This shows what the [Big-O-Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) really does: abstract away from constant factors such as *complexity1* and *complexity2*.

**If each iteration requires O(f(n))**, then your total time complexity will be O(n*f(n)).

**If each iteration makes a recursive call**, i.e. calls `dummy_algorithm` with a smaller parameter, you do need a recurrence relation to compute the time complexity. How the recurrence relation looks like depends on how often you make recursive calls and with what parameter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation shows you how to find and solve the appropriate recurrence relation.